# Git redo a botched up merge as easy as possible

Tags: git

Ok so I just finished this interesting dive into git

Two developers sharing working against one origin.
A merge goes really really bad and about a weeks worth of work is removed from subsequent commits. 
Developers keep on working for a day before they realise how bad it was and have produced a couple of commits between the merge point and HEAD.

What is the easiest way to resolve this?

My take on it was to

```
git checkout develop_branch
git branch develop_branch_old
git checkout -b tmp_branch
git branch -f develop_branch commit_that_was_develop_branch_before_the_unfortunate_merge
git push origin --delete develop_branch
git checkout develop_branch
git merge feature_branch_x
//resolve merge conflicts in a more... uhm... controlled manner
git push origin develop_branch
git push origin develop_branch_old
git branch -D tm_branch
```

Tell the developers to clone out a new copy and copy paste over the changes from the last 24 hours and then throw away there old repo and continue working in the new and then, once everything was sorted out

```
git push origin --delete develop_branch_old
```

So I have multiple questions

- Can this be done any easier?
- Is this even a sane way of doing it?
- What if they had kept on working for like a week or a month? Then the work after the error can't easily be copy pasted
- What if there were loads of developers can I fix this without deleting the original branch?

Comment: Please attach example of commits tree they get in result. It will be easier to understand the situation. And what do you mean by 'resolving' this? Do you want to undo merge or ..? Not really clear.

Comment: How much work happened in 24 hours?  Git will happily let you check out files across branches, and if you do something like `git checkout -p` it will even let you pick which parts of which files you want to check out.  Between that and `git cherry-pick` you should be able to reset *develop_branch* to before the merge and bring all the changes you care back into it. If you post a tree as Max mentioned, it would be easier to give more specific instructions.